# Is there a way to add BaseGameUtils library project as a gradle dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, basegameutils

I have been using **BaseGameUtils** library as another module in my project. Since gradle's introduced it is very easy to add third-party libraries to the project using the dependency management system .

I would like to add **BaseGameUtils** as a gradle dependency from any official repositories. This will make importing easy and i don't have to worry about the changes they make to this official library. Otherwise how do we know if a major change has done to this project ?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: I don't get the question. Just add it as a dependency...

Comment: @Henry here i had to add library as a directory to the root folder of my project before i add it as a dependency.  Any way to avoid adding directory and depend this project source code from live repository like maven ?

Comment: Sure, if its creators have deployed it to a repository (I don't know if they have).